# I need help setting up Mercurial for windows for very uninformed users

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial

I'm the uninformed user. I want to use mercurial for my personal use in terms of writing code and writing papers and have every change be accessible. I'm not a programmer by trade, I run a lot of matlab code and that's it as far as programming experience goes. I've installed the TortoiseHg with Windows Explorer "shell" integration all-in-one package. I already have python 2.7 installed too.

Next I went to this tutorial: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TutorialInstall  and I got lost right away. They say the mercurial program is called hg, so I type so in the search function and it comes up, I open it and a quick command window opens up and closes in a fraction of a second and that's it, nothing else happens. I read a bit further into the tutorial and they say that you have to type hg in the prompt. I tried windows powershell and this did work but I don't know if I was supposed to be doing this from within some hg prompt or something.

I went to the next step of the tutorial and they go through the steps of making a repository. I blindly typed the commands they have setup and it worked until I typed "ls -a" saying that it's not a recognized cmdlet.

I don't know what I'm doing and I need a better resource that helps me get this set up and running as I don't understand why even opening "hg" does apparently nothing or if even I should be using powershell for the tutorial.

Comment: You might want start with GUI (TortoiseHG Workbench) program instead of the command line. Note that Mercurial works best with pure text files, so it is not an optimal tool for binary files such as Word documents. (Which is what I assume when you mentioned writing papers)

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is mainly used by people who *are* programmers by trade...so all the tutorials are written for programmers, and therefore assume a certain understanding of how command line applications work.

I suspect you're not *that* familiar with the command line, so first of all, I second user694733's comment:
**For a beginner, the TortoiseHG GUI is *way* easier to get started.

(and they have [excellent documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/docs.html) as well)**

---

Anyway, here's why the command line didn't work like you expected:

1. `hg` is a command line application. When you directly start it from Windows *(which you did by typing `hg` in the Windows start menu)*, it behaves like you described: it pops up and immediately disappears. **You need it to start from the Windows command line instead.**
2. There are two different command lines in Windows:

   a) Windows PowerShell, which you already used

   b) the "classic" Windows command line, which you can open by typing `cmd` into the search box in the Windows start menu

There's no special "hg prompt", it's just that you're supposed to run `hg` in one of the two command line interfaces I listed above. It doesn't matter which one you use - `hg` behaves the same in both.

3. > it worked until I typed "ls -a" saying that it's not a recognized cmdlet.

Mercurial does not only work on Windows, but on other operating systems as well *(Linux and Mac OS, for example)*.
The `hg` commands are the same everywhere, but everything else is different depending on your operating system. For example, `ls` is the Linux command to list the content of a directory. In Windows, it's `dir` instead.
Most, if not all, of the Mercurial developers don't use Windows, so their tutorials are not written with Windows in mind.

You should really  start with TortoiseHG, as mentioned above *(its documentation is Windows friendly, too)* or if you really want to use the command line, I'd suggest a different tutorial, [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/), which was written by a Windows guy *(Joel Spolsky, [the CEO of Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about/management), the company that runs Stack Overflow)*.